# How can I turn off light in compositing nodes?

Tags: compositing-nodes, light

I want to animate this neon light to be complete turned off but it still shows some light after I put zero on everything, what can I do?

I basiclly explain everything in this picture.

Thanks. And sorry for my English.

[image]

Comment: What do the materials on the heart and the word 'DREAM' look like? It might be that the pink light is in the render layer, in which case you may not be able to totally remove it in compositing.

Comment: The material is what you see in the right corner, it's just white emission, the color is added in compositing (in the nodegroup its color and blurr).

Comment: That's an interesting way to do it!  Would you mind sharing the blend file?  It may make it easier to trouble-shoot?

Comment: I might be able to share my file later, but I followed this tutorial on Youtube to create the compositing: https://youtu.be/m2MPtp4N4_o?t=634 (I added timestamp to the link).

Answer (score 1):

When I followed the tutorial, I needed to deselect Ambient Occlusion in the World tab in order to make everything black.
[image: Ambient Occlusion]

Also, in the compositing nodes, I forgot to connect the image to the second mix node, and that caused my lower text to always appear.[image: Missing Connection]